# How to mix pixel colors in Shader?

Tags: opengl, shaders, directx, glsl, hlsl

I have a pixel that have a colour RGB. This color is calculated by the shader and can be anything.

How can I override this color by a colour I choose. If my pixel is white it's simple, I can do this:

```
half3 original = half3(1, 1, 1);
half3 mycolor = half3(1, 0, 0);
half3 result = original * mycolor;
```

But what can I do if:

```
half3 original = half3(0.36, 0.74, 0.18);
half3 mycolor = half3(1, 0, 0);
half3 result = ?;
```

What operation or function should I apply to my original pixel color to override it ?

Comment: I don't get the problem here. What is the problem with "result = mycolor;"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was very easy finally. Here is the answer. I am using an external value.

```
half3 original = half3(0.36, 0.74, 0.18);
half3 mycolor = half3(1, 0, 0);
half value = 0.5;
half3 result = original * value + mycolor * (1 - value);
```

You could also use `mix();` or `lerp();` depending on your platform.

Comment: result = mix(mycolor, original, value);

Comment: The mix function doesn't appears in the [NVidia developer zone](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/index_stdlib.html)... This function is only available in [OpengGL](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/mix.xml), no ?

Comment: GLSL is just my flavor of choice, in HLSL it's called `lerp()`

Answer (score 6):

Just

```
half3 result = (original + mycolor) / 2;
```

does what you'd expect because the arithmetic operators are overridden for the `half3` type.